# Phpmyadmin and mysql showing wrong results

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to make a item shop for my rpg I have a table called itemslist
with 3 columns itemname, itemprice, image,

So at the moment i have 1 entry in there itemname is Potion itemprice is 1000 and image is hey just to test with.

The image column I'm having problems with. For some reason it is echoing out has 1 and not hey. Even tho in phpmyadmin its hey. All columns are var except for the price.

The problem is if I change the price to 99 it will echo out he image has 9 if i change itemprice to 10 it will echo out the column image has 0. Even tho in the db the column image is hey and the price is 10 it will echo out he price has 10 and the image has 0 on the page for some reason its getting the last number of the price and thinking that is the image column

```
include_once('config.php');
$item = $_POST['item'];
$item = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item']);
$item2 = preg_replace('/[^a-z]/i', null, $item);

/// Get the item price 
$sql55 = "SELECT * FROM itemslist WHERE itemname='$item2'";
$result55 = mysql_query($sql55) or die(mysql_error());
$itemprice = mysql_fetch_array($result55);


$sql555 = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']." '";
$result555 = mysql_query($sql555) or die(mysql_error());
$usermoney = mysql_fetch_array($result555);

$itemname = $itemprice['itemname'] ;
$itemprice = $itemprice['itemprice'] ;
$itemimage = $itemprice['image'] ;


echo  $itemimage ;


if ($usermoney['money']  > $itemprice['itemprice']) {
  echo "You have just bought a ";
  echo $itemname ;




    mysql_query("INSERT INTO `items` (`item`, `belongsto`, `itemimage`) VALUES ('$itemname','".$_SESSION['username']."','$itemimage')") or die(mysql_error());  


   $result23123 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET money=money-$itemprice WHERE username = '{$_SESSION['username']}'")
or die(mysql_error());
}else{
echo"Your to poor to buy this item";
die;
}
```

In side config.php I have the session start and mysql connect.

Table structure

`itemslist` table

```
itemname, itemprice, image
```

Then for items table its item ,belongsto,itemimage

from itemslist  and the name of it and insert it into then items table. 
But the problem is if the itemprice  has a number in it lets say 12 then i echo out the column next to it which is image and image will show the number 2 ( the 2 from the end of the itemprice)

There are no errors showing on page.  But has i have said its echoign out that the  image is 2  when in the db its hey. The column for the image is var so do not know why its echoing out has 2

Comment: Please include some debug data i.e. a dump of $itemprice and the INSERT query

Comment: Can you also provide the table structure?

Comment: Can you explain correctly what the error is ?

Comment: "You're too poor" not "Your to poor".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're overwriting the array `$itemprice` with the string `$itemprice['itemprice']`. Change the variable name to $iteminfo and it'll work fine.

```
$iteminfo = mysql_fetch_array($result55);
//...
$itemname = $iteminfo['itemname'] ;
$itemprice = $iteminfo['itemprice'];
$itemimage = $iteminfo['image'] ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using  print_r to get a better idea what is in your $itemprice variable.

```
echo  $itemimage ;
// becomes
print_r $itemimage ;
```